# Computability: Proving a predicate is not recursively enumerable

Tags: computability, recursion, halting-problem, primitive-recursion, predicate-logic

Let P(p) <=>  for each x, comp(p,x) is defined.

Can anyone explain to me how to prove that P is not RE (recursively enumerable) ?

Comment: What is "comp(p,x)"?

Comment: Presumably, "comp(p,x) is defined" is the same as program $p$ halting on input $x$. Your predicate then states that $p$ is *total*, and is known to be [$\Pi_2$-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy).

Answer (score 1):

Show that your predicate is coRE-hard, that is, every coRE predicate reduces to it. If your predicate were RE, then it would follow that RE=coRE, which is known to be false.

The rest of the answer assumes that "comp(p,x) is defined" is the same as "program $p$ halts on input $x$".

In order to show that your predicate is coRE-hard, you need to show that for every coRE predicate $Q$ there is a computable function $f$ such that $Q(z)$ iff $P(f(z))$. A predicate $Q$ is coRE if there is a computable function $q$ such that $Q(z)$ iff for all $x$, $q(z,x)$. Hence we need

> for all $x$, $q(z,x)$ iff for all $x$, $f(z)$ halts on $x$.

You take it from here.

(In fact, your predicate is [$\Pi_2$-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy).)

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about defining f(q,y) that returns the code of g. With g being g(x) = 0 if not T(q,y,x) and undefined otherwise.  (T Kleene predicate). Then use that f

Comment: Nobody here can be assumed to know your notations, neither "comp" nor "T". Try to use "program $p$ halts on $x$", "program $p$ accepts $x$", and the like.

Comment: Duly noted. This is my second post as my first one was this exact question but in the wrong section

Comment: Alternatively, you can keep your notations, but first *define* them.